# Tips for finding the range of a function

Tags: probability, functions

I am studying probability, specifically joint probability distributions. When computing sums or quotients I end up with things like this (when working with uniform random variables for instance):

$$\int_a^bf_x(x)f_y(z-x)dx  $$

$$ 0 \le z-x \le 1$$
$$0 \le x  \le 1$$
or

$$\int_a^bf_x(x)f_y(zx)dx  $$
$$ 0 \le zx \le 1$$
$$0 \le x  \le 1$$

In both cases the functions $f_y$ and $f_x$ are defined as 1 between 0 and 1 and 0 otherwise. The solutions always involve breaking the integral apart between $z < 1$ and $2-z$ or something like that.

I'm having a hard time figuring out where it's supposed to 'break'. What are the general rules here? Is there a common method that can help me?

Thanks.